# how to add a new files to existing makefile project

Tags: c, makefile, configure, autoconf, pidgin

I am trying to add some functionality to existing makefile project. I wrote some .c and .h files. After some googling time I found that Makefile.am should be modified and  run autoreconf will do what I need.

Can some one please explain how to do this exactly?

Thank you.
FYI
I am trying to compile http://sipe.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the Makefile.am found under the directory where you've kept you .c and .h files. Take a look at [this](http://repo.or.cz/w/siplcs.git/blob/5090d628c1d362ef46b9fcafffcb2b6b47e8af96:/src/telepathy/Makefile.am) file if you've .c file under telepathy directory, add your .c file in this Makefile.am. Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks rakib.

I found very useful information here http://mij.oltrelinux.com/devel/autoconf-automake/

and manual http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Writing-Autoconf-Input